# Qt Creator causes an endless compilation loop on Ubuntu

Tags: qt, qt-creator, ubuntu-10.10

I got a project folder up on a Mac, and it works nicely. I moved the folder to Ubuntu, opened [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) in Ubuntu, loaded up my project and build

Build never ends, getting an endless loop of a message about my project file having modifications "in the future", "entering folder/leaving folder" and so on forever...

What's going on?

Comment: Can you attach your .pro file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess sometimes you have to take things literally. the "Modifications in the future" was resolved as soon as I got my *.pro file under a text editor and saved it back. It's a strange and annoying bug, but easily resolved.

thanks.